# Scheduled task throws System.IO.IOException

Tags: .net, scheduled-tasks, ioexception, windows-server-2016

I have a problem with serveral scheduled tasks on Windows server 2016. On the running server, we have serveral scheduled tasks running. Some of them sporadically throws a System.IO.IOException. The error appears in the eventviewer as a .NET Runtime error and a Application error.

.NET Runtime error:

```
Application: NameOfScheduledtask.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.IOException
   at System.IO.FileStream.VerifyOSHandlePosition()
   at System.IO.FileStream.WriteCore(Byte[], Int32, Int32)
   at System.IO.FileStream.FlushWrite(Boolean)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Dispose(Boolean)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Finalize()
```

Application error:

```
Faulting application name: NameOfScheduledtask.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5c767522
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.14393.2636, time stamp: 0x5bda8043
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000db0b2
Faulting process id: 0x2704
Faulting application start time: 0x01d4dd74d7c09aee
Faulting application path: PathToScheduledTask
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 00f31a09-bbad-4ec9-bbf2-f779b5800320
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

We have a base class for handling logging, and this error appears before entering the first log statement in the code. So it looks to me like our code never runs.

The settings of the tasks:

[image]

The trigger of the task:
[image]

I look for guidance to why this happens, and what I can do to fix the issue.

Comment: Does your common logging writes to file? If so I wouldn't assume that it's not hit it could be as well the cause of an issue. Can you share details of how your logging works?

Comment: Yes. The logging we use is the NLOG framework, and it is set to log to file. 

We also have a performancelog that logs to database. That log is logged to first. But this log is not to be found either, when IO Exception happens.

Comment: It's going to be very dificult to determine the cause of an issue with such limited information. In my opinion you could try wrapping whole process in try catch if possible ,since it seems like error occurs in place you wouldn't expect and is not handeled, and try logging more details from exception maybe to other source than file since your logging mechanism may be the cause of an error, maybe try eventviewer, stack trace should point you in the right place

Comment: Inside the main method, I wrapped the code in a try-catch. So if the logging code failed, it would write to Microsoft eventlog with a specific ID so I could search the eventlog afterwards. Today I filtered the eventlog by my ID, but got no hits. I did however still see the application errors mentioned in this post. So I suspect the windows task scheduler is the problem. Do you now any special task scheduler log I can dig into ?